# Data is available in DataAccess Tier but not in Presentation Tier

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wcf, n-tier-architecture, presentation

I am building an nTier application following a tutorial.  The simple project connected to Northwind worked.

The application uses a DataEntityTier, a DataAccessTier, a dataset split between the two (the dataset.designer.vb is in the DataEntityTier), a WCF Data Service with IService1.vb and Service1.vb containing the OperationContract code and Function code in Service1.vb to return data from two tables.

The presentation tier references the DataEntityTier and has a Service Reference to the WCF Data Service.  I am able to obtain data from Northwind in the PresentationTier.  (I am also able to connect via Excel and obtain data).

I am now building a simple project connecting to my own SQL database.  I have double-checked all my code and it is the same as in the test project.  I am able to obtain data in the DataAccessTier when I go to the Query Builder on the table in the XSD dataset GUI.

Although data is visible in the XSD dataset, it is not coming through to the PresentationTier.  No errors are thrown but it appears to be failing in the DataService at Service1.vb.  This code is identical to my Northwind project and Intellisense shows expected properties -

```
Public Function GetClientInfo() As DataEntityTier.PPDataSet.tblClientInfoDataTable   Implements IService1.GetClientInfo
Dim ClientInfoTableAdapter1 As New DataAccessTier.PPDataSetTableAdapters.tblClientInfoTableAdapter
Return ClientInfoTableAdapter1.GetClientInfo
End Function
```

What is the best way to trouble shoot why the data isn't making it through to the PresentationTier?

Comment: this is the ntier walkthrough I used:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx

Comment: I have now run a SELECT INTO and moved my table to the Northwind database.  I rebuilt the entire Northwind n-tier walkthrough project from scratch. I can get data from the existing Northwind tables, but not from the new imported table.  I added a Primary Key to the table and that did not change it.  The Presentation Tier is still not able to pick up that one table.

Comment: I have now copied the Northwind Customers table into my database and added it to the XSD dataset.  The Presentation Tier receives data from the Northwind table in the new database, but data from the other tables still does not carry through.  Is there some attribute a table needs so it can pass through WCF and available to the Presentation Tier?

Comment: CREATED ANOTHER MORE SPECIFIC QUESTION HERE:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553784/vb-net-wcf-one-table-is-available-in-presentation-tier-the-other-is-not